# Long Transaction On File Upload Locks Strategies

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, locking

I need to upload files to some SFTP or FTP servers (using libcurl) and register them in database.

For this I have several tables

```
-- locations to store files - some SFTP and FTP servers
CREATE TABLE locations(
  id bigint,
  size_quota bigint, -- maximum amount of data, that location can store
  priority real      -- like metric for network interfaces - more is better
  /* server params like URL and etc omitted for simplicity */
);

-- files located on those servers
CREATE TABLE files(
  id bigint IDENTITY(1,1),
  loc_id bigint,  -- location id
  size bigint     -- file size
  /* file params like path and etc omitted for simplicity */
);

-- example data
INSERT INTO locations
VALUES (0, 100, 1.0) (1, 100, 2.0);

INSERT INTO files
VALUES(0, 50), (1, 60)
```

So, to register file in database, I need to chose a location for it. Basically its just `SELECT TOP 1 id, FROM locations ORDER BY priority DESC;` but i need to account `size_quota` of locations.

So, it can be

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT TOP 1 loc.id from locations loc
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT COALESCE(sum(size), 0) total_size, loc_id
  FROM files
  WITH (HOLDLOCK) -- note the holdlock I need to hold it to prevent quota overflow due to race conditions
  GROUP BY loc_id
) sq ON sq.loc_id = loc.id
WHERE loc.size_quote - sq.total_size > 50 -- 50 is the size of file being uploaded
ORDER BY loc.priority DESC
```

Then there comes file uploading operation, which is quite long - files are large - they can be several gigabytes in size.

And then

```
INSERT INTO files (loc_id, size) VALUES(chosen_loc_id, 50);
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Obviously, that `HOLDLOCK` strikes performance hard because there is only one file can be uploaded at a time.

How can I evade that? I thought a solution with another table with space reserves, but there is possibility, that client will fail and reserve will stuck in database.

Comment: You could note "who" reserved "what" and "when" and then free the reserved space if it was not used for some reason. After a day or if you can detect that the client failed etc. The client might even give a timeout - "I reserve 3GB and will be done in 2 hours" and it knows to scrap it and try again when it gets longer than 2 hours (or ask for a timeout extension if the upload is slower than expected) and you know that it failed if it still remains only "reserved" after those 2 hours.

Comment: "To prevent quota overflow" - this resembles me how some credit card transactions work. Transaction effectively happens in two stages. The whole amount of the transaction (the whole file size in your case) is reserved at first. During this reservation there are checks that credit limit (quota) is not exceeded. Then there is lengthy processing of the transaction (file upload). When everything is OK transaction is finalized and is marked as complete. If something is wrong (file upload failed after few retries), reservation is removed.

Comment: Ty for commentaries. It seems, that reserves is the way to go, but it assumes some third entity that will cleanup expired reserves. I wanted to avoid this, but if there is no better option...